# How can i exploit SQLiteDatabase.CustomFunction?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I followed this [article](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/install.wiki) and successfully created a binding library for android, last night. I was able to run test queries and they were OK. Now I'm trying to add my own user defined function to the connection.

Here is the code that I have written to add this function:

```
class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public MyHelper(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx, DB_PATH.getPath(), null, 1);
        }

        public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA key = 'secret'");
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE t1(x)");
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int iOld, int iNew) {
        }
    }

    MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.addCustomFunction("testfunc", 1, new SQLiteDatabase.CustomFunction() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String[] args) {
                args[0] = args[0] + "test";
            }
        });
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('ali'), ('asghar'), ('toraby')");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT testfunc(x) as test , x FROM t1", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("x"));
            String str2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("test"));
            Log.d("Test" , str);
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Although The function is added successfully and it does not say that `testfunc`  does not exist, it does not return anything. As you see the callback interface method does not have any output, So how can I return a value from within a custom function?

I also tried the following implementation of `CustomFunction`, but it returns null again:

```
db.addCustomFunction("testfunc", 1, new SQLiteDatabase.CustomFunction() {
            @Override
            public String callback(String[] args) {
                return args[0];
            }
        });
```

Thank for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

The source code (android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp) says:

```cpp
// TODO: Support functions that return values.
```

Comment: I tried CustomFunction with String output but neither String nor void seems that does not work.